# dropzone form comes in whole body.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I juse this code for intragating dropzone in  a normal form

Index.php

```
        <form id="my-awesome-dropzone"  class="dropzone" action="upload.php">
          <div class="dropzone-previews"> </div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->

          <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
          <input type="text" name="Name" />
          <input type="text" name="Description" />

          <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>

        </form>
```

custom dropzone JS

```
   Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 
   autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: false,
         parallelUploads: 100,
          maxFiles: 100,


    init: function() {
var myDropzone = this;


this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});


this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
  alert("successfully");
});
this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
  alert("successfully");

});
this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
  alert("Error");

});}}
```

Pls Help me expert brother! the drop down form comes with whole form. what i need to be fixed in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the whole question but I see only few problems in your code.

In the following snippet I updated your code in order to see the alert messages:

```js
$(function () {
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    init: function () {
      var myDropzone = this;

      this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
      });
    },
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
      alert('sending');
    },
    sendingmultiple: function (file, xhr, formData) {
      alert("successfully");
    },
    successmultiple: function (file, xhr, formData) {
      alert("successfully");

    },
    error: function (a, errorMessage, xhr) {
      alert("Error");
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>

<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="upload.php">
    <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->

    <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
    <input type="text" name="Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="Description"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for you valuable time.! I see your snippet. did you see the "drop files here to upload option " over-right with whole form. But I need it above the fields only! can you give me suggestion for it. Please

Comment: @SaifMorshed Thanks you for the comment. To help you I need to understand what you are looking for. I'm sorry, but I cannot understand your "But I need it above the fields only! ". Could you be so kind to clarify this concempt? Thanks again

Comment: thank you very much to reply me again. "But I need it above the fields only! " it means I want to say the drag and drop work with whole body. But I want to work only one area where I want to display. So i want to display it above the the fields.

Comment: @SaifMorshed Try now and let me know. I added only previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',